# how to get a textbox value into a string var in javascript file using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to get the textbox(id="lunch-menu") value into a string in my js file using angularjs but not using any DOM statement. I tried to do it but nothing worked. I am new to angularjs. Please help how i can do that.

This is my js and html file

```js
(function () {
 // body...
 'use strict';
 angular.module('LunchCheck', [])
 .controller('LunchCheckController', LunchCheckController);

 LunchCheckController.$inject=['$scope'];
 function LunchCheckController($scope) {

    //code to get the textbox user input value into a string
 }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Lunch Checker</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="LunchCheckApp.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="LunchCheck">
  <div class="conatainer" ng-controller="LunchCheckController">
 <h1>Lunch Checker</h1>
    <div class="form-group form-control">
          <input id="lunch-menu" type="text" placeholder="list comma separated dishes you usually have for lunch" ng-model="userInput">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
           <button class="btn btn-default">Check If Too Much</button>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group message"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what about takeing `ng-model` value to your controller

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a two-way-binding (`ng-model`) on your input.

Now you just have to access that in your controller:

```
function LunchCheckController($scope) {
   //code to get the textbox user input value into a string
   var value = $scope.userInput;
}
```

Comment: i tried that but when i am printing it on console it is giving me undefined value. I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function () {
 // body...
 'use strict';
 angular.module('LunchCheck', [])
 .controller('LunchCheckController', LunchCheckController);

 LunchCheckController.$inject=['$scope'];
 function LunchCheckController($scope) {
      var launchcheck=angular.element('#lunch-menu').val('');
      //var launchcheck=$scope.userInput;
    //code to get the textbox user input value into a string

 }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Lunch Checker</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="LunchCheckApp.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="LunchCheck">
  <div class="conatainer" ng-controller="LunchCheckController">
 <h1>Lunch Checker</h1>
    <div class="form-group form-control">
          <input id="lunch-menu" type="text" placeholder="list comma separated dishes you usually have for lunch" ng-model="userInput">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
           <button class="btn btn-default">Check If Too Much</button>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group message"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is not working when printing launchcheck variable on console it is printing undefined

Comment: I change here please see it var launchcheck=angular.element('#lunch-menu').val('');

Comment: its not working it is giving me error- Error: [jqLite:nosel] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/jqLite/nosel and moreover it is using DOM, i want to do it without using DOM